# passing a php variable in $_POST

Tags: php, sql, forms, variables, post

i have a question regarding passing a php variable in the $_POST knowing that i named my buttons using the same variable because i want the buttons to have unique names.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

        $friend_id = $row['friend_id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id = '$friend_id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $friendname = mysql_result($result,0,"username");
    $friendname = sanitize($friendname);
    echo '<input type = "submit"  id='. $friend_id .'  name ='.$friend_id.' class = "member" value ='. $friendname.' /><br>';
    }
```

here where i am trying to pass it but it is not working

```
print_r($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['name'])){


    $signers =  mysql_query("SELECT friend_id  FROM friends WHERE user_id = $session_user_id ");
    $count =    mysql_num_rows($signers);
    if($count == 0){
        echo "<p>you need to add team members</p>";
    }

else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($signers)){

        $signer_id .= $row['friend_id'];

}
echo '<p>'.$signer_id . '</p>';
}
$request = mysql_query("INSERT INTO requests VALUES ('','$user_id','$fid','$fname','$signer_id')");
}
else {

    echo '<p> not working </p>';
}
```

both of those sections are in the same php page

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Change `$_POST["'$friend_id'"]` to `$_POST['$friend_id']` you have double and single quotes. probably a Copy/Paste hiccup

Comment: i actually tried that and it also did not work

Answer (score 2):

You're not passing a variable around, you're passing a value so this line -

```
if(isset($_POST["'$friend_id'"])=== true){
```

needs to be changed to this -

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
```

The `name` attribute (along with the value) of each input is what is passed in a POST. You're just checking to see if the name parameter has a value, if it does then you can act on it with other code.

In addition please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: thank you so much but again it did not enter the if statement,  and i will keep in mind the other information.

Comment: Just before your `if` do a `print_r($_POST)` so you can see what is in the POST array @dalia

Comment: it actually printed out the user id and name as such Array ( [7] => lolita )

Comment: So it must be getting into the `if` statement @dalia. You're not doing any error checking on your queries, perhaps there is a problem there? Add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. You can also find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: but it directly goes to the else statement . thank you so much for your help

Comment: The `while` in the `else` is trying to get data from the query run in the first part of the `if`. That will not work.

Comment: i did not mean  the else inside the major if i was talking about the else that maens in $_post is not set

Comment: I only see one `else`. Now that I have fixed indenting I can see what you're doing and your code flows OK. Until you add MySQl error checking we may never know what is happening. How are you setting `$session_user_id`?

Comment: i did and i don't see anything the last error is hours ago

Comment: Hmmmm, then I am not sure what to tell you. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: thank you you have been very helpful just when i did the error displaying i got an error saying i need to use mysqli

Comment: Either MySQLi or PDO @dalia. Check the links in my answer.

Comment: but could that be ever the reason of the problem i thought it cant be

Comment: Yes, because your POST would be blank.

Comment: i will change it but i am just trying to get my mind around it when we print it out it contained something

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the second piece of code should be without quotes:

```
if (isset($_POST[$friend_id])) {...
```

The part `=== true` isn't necessary in this case, I've removed it.

Comment: @xNeyte isset($var) returns a boolean

Comment: @dalia: is the form sent by POST method?

Comment: @panther yes the method is set <form action = "" method = "post" name = "member" id = "members">

Comment: @what is the real `name` of this input when you show generated source code? Does this value orrecpond with `$friend_id`?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into predefining any variables you intend to use.

```
function input_post ($value, $default) {
   return isset($_POST[$value]) ? $_POST['value'] : false;
}
```

Then use the post as so, this would prevent any not set errors

```
 $friend_id = input_post('friend_id');

 if ($friend_id) {
    // If friend_id is set, do this
 }
 else {
    // If friend_id is false or unset
 }
```